# .htaccess exclude URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have working htaccess, which block specific countries and/or languages,

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^NL$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^BY$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^UA$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^RU$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (nl) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (be) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (uk) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cap.html [L]
```

but I need to give access to specific route eg api.html to any country/language. 
I try to add exception

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api\.html
```

but it does not work, I've tried hundreds of conditions but gave up for 6 hours, please advise what I'm doing wrong.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # Exclude countries, forbidden by law
    RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^NL$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^BY$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^UA$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^RU$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (nl) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (be) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (uk) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api\.html
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cap.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^NL$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^BY$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^UA$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^RU$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (nl) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (be) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (uk) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru) [NC]
#rewrite everything to "cap.html" except "api.html"
RewriteRule ^((?!api\.html).*)$ cap.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code seems logical, but you can try by merging the conditions together, and moving the last condition to the top:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(?:NL|BY|UA|RU)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (?:nl|be|uk|ru) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ cap.html [L]
```

Comment: I've tried, regexp "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api\.html [NC]" works, but problem is in next loops of next rules - all to index.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem in little bit different way
Just created api.php file and added rule to skip existing files

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(?:NL|BY|UA|RU)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (?:nl|be|uk|ru) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ cap.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```